# AppHostBase.Instance has already been set after already working

Tags: api, servicestack, github-issues

I have an ASP.Net WEB API using ServiceStack.  The API had been previously working but is now throwing the "AppHostBase.The instance has already been set".  I haven't changed any code since the last time I debugged it successfully.  But *something* must have changed.

I am calling the ServiceStack Assembly in AppHost.cs:

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(App_Start.AppHost), "Start")]
```

Then in the Start method:

```
public static void Start()
{
    new AppHost().Init();
}
```

This then fires the configure method which throws the error. Any ideas why the "AppHostBase.The instance has already been set" error has suddenly shown up?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have multiple `PreApplicationStartMethod` registrations somewhere? Or some other reflection functionality invoking this code.

The Exception indicates that the AppHost initialization is being called twice, you can try checking using a static flag to verify that it's being called twice, e.g:

```
static hasInit = false;
public static void Start()
{
    if (hasInit) throw new Exception("Start() Called twice");
    new AppHost().Init();
    hasInit = true;
}
```